# Convert UTC to local time

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a fairly large dataset that has UTC timestamps. I need to convert the UTC to local (central) timezone..I tried my google-fu, to no avail.

Dataframe is below.

```
STID UTCTIME TRES  VRIR  RETY  REWT WEDN  DELP  WDIR  DERT RTAX  GAIN  DEVD
0  ARFW  2012-01-01T00:00  28.47  65  -999  -999  41  41  289  12  20  0  0
1  ARFW  2012-01-01T00:30  28.55  62  -999  -999  32  33  359  23  31  0  0
2  ARFW  2012-01-01T01:00  28.59  60  -999  -999  29  30  345  19  26  0  0
3  ARFW  2012-01-01T01:30  28.63  60  -999  -999  24  25  339  20  27  0  0
4  ARFW  2012-01-01T02:00  28.66  58  -999  -999  22  25  335  24  30  0  0

#Define time as UTC
data_df['UTCTIME'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['UTCTIME'], utc= True)



data_df.dtypes
STID               object
UTCTIME    datetime64[ns]
TRES              float64
.
.
.
GAIN              float64
DEVD                int64
dtype: object
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
import pytz, datetime
utc = pytz.utc
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
CSTM= pytz.timezone('US/Central')
local = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(data_df['UTCTIME'], fmt)
CSTM_dt = CSTM.localize(dt)
```

and the error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-f10301993777> in <module>()
      4 CSTM = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
      5 local = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
----> 6 dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(data_df['UTCTIME'], fmt)
      7 CSTM = CSTM.localize(dt)

TypeError: must be string, not Series
```

Also, there are duplicate entries for UTCTIME...I can't comprehend indexing...and I believe indexing could be one issue here..I am not sure what is missing here.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your input strings to the function are well-formed, i.e. in the expected format?  The ValueError message suggests that you are trying to parse a string "UTCTIME" from the timestamp format.

Comment: Nevertheless, "UTCTIME" is not a valid timestamp.  You do not appear to be parsing the datetime strings properly from the input file.

Comment: Could you provide any examples for reference?

Answer (score 0):

In your code in the `strptime` line you do not use the actual date string from your dataframe, but the literal string "UTCTIME".

```
from_zone = tz.gettz('UTCTIME')
to_zone = tz.tzlocal()
utc = datetime.strptime('UTCTIME', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')  # <====== STRING
utc = utc.replace(tzinfo = from_zone)
central = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
```

If you want to use that on your dataframe, you either need to loop over the UTCTIME column or create a helper function doing your conversion and use the `DataFrame.column.apply(helperfunc)` method.

To only test your code, replace the `'UTCTIME'` string with a actual date string or use a variable with the string.